# Red and Blue Balls

Tags: probability

Find the probability in the general case that in between any two red balls 
are at least two blue balls.

So, at first, I tried to approach the problem by thinking about the probability 
that no two red balls are drawn consecutively and I found that this probability 
is

$P(\text{no two red balls drawn consecutively})=
\dfrac{\binom{b+1}{r}}{\binom{r+b}{r}}$

where $r$ is the number of red balls and $b$ is the number of blue balls.

I'm not sure how to use this information to solve the problem.

Comment: subtract this from $1$.

Comment: No two red balls are drawn consecutively can happen even if there is at least **one** blue ball between red balls.

Comment: Please describe the precise situation you are talking about. All we are told so far is that there might be red balls and blue balls and drawings somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, for the condition to be fulfilled, there must be at least $2(r-1)$ blue balls.

I will illustrate the method with a numerical example. You can easily work out the general formula from it. Suppose $r = 3, b = 6$

Form $3$ blocks with a red ball followed by $2$ blue ones except for the last red ball:

$\uparrow\color{red}\bullet\color{blue}{\bullet\bullet}\;\;\uparrow\color{red}\bullet\color{blue}{\bullet\bullet}\;\;\uparrow\color{red}\bullet\uparrow$

There are $4$  places for the $2$ extra blues at the uparrows

By stars and bars, they can be placed in $\binom{2+4-1}{2} = 10$ ways

Put $x = b - 2(r-1),$ for the extra blues to be placed, in  $(r+1)$ compartments

Easy now to work out a general formula for the number of valid arrangements, and the Pr.

Number of valid ways $= \binom{r+x}{x}$

$Pr = \dfrac{\binom{r+x}{x}}{\binom{r+b}{b}}$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly there are $r+b\choose r$ ways to arrange $r$ red and $b$ blue balls without restriction, so that'll be the denominator for any probability.

For the purpose of this problem, it's convenient to imagine always placing $2$ additional blue balls at the far end of any arrangement.  Doing so allows us to reformulate the restriction as saying that each red ball is immediately followed by at least $2$ blue balls.  This means we are simply arranging $r$ triplets, each consisting of a red followed by two blue balls, and $b+2-2r$ blue-ball singlets.  Thus the desired probability is

$${b+2-r\choose r}\over{r+b\choose r}$$